# Not able to write an return of a function to file

Tags: python, file-io, io, format

Can anyone explain me why I am not able to do this and if there is any workaroud?

This works for ex.

```
a, b, c, d = extract(text)

fw.write("Number of SMS: {0} \nCharacters before extraction: {1} \nCharacter after extraction: {2} \nOverhead: {3:.0f}%".format(a, b, c, d))
```

But this does not

```
fw.write("Number of SMS: {0} \nCharacters before extraction: {1} \nCharacter after extraction: {2} \nOverhead: {3:.0f}%".format(extract(text)))
```

Comment: What is the `extract` function?

Comment: Change `... .format(extract(text)))` to `... .format(*extract(text)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `extract()` returns a tuple, you need to unpack the return value before passing it to format:

```
.format(*extract(text))
```

the asterisk does the trick here.

**Explanation:** in Python, `string#format` has the following signature:

```
.format(*args, **keyword_args)
```

The `*` and `**` are known as the unpacking operators (in Ruby, they are called splats). Their sole purpose is to transform lists (tuples, arrays) and dictionaries (dicts, objects) into argument lists, respectively.

`extract()` returns a list, but format is expecting an argument list. So before, you have:

```
#if the output of extract(text) is ('foo', 'bar') or ['foo', 'bar']
.format(extract(text)) # this thing
.format(('foo', 'bar')) # is equivalent to this, note the parentheses
```

In this case, the tuple ('foo', 'bar') is equal to the first format token `{0}`, and format doesn't know what to do with a tuple token (which of the elements of the tuple should I use?).

When you use the expansion operator, you are transforming the output of `extract()` into the list the function is expecting, so:

```
#if the output of extract(text) is ('foo', 'bar') or ['foo', 'bar']
.format(*extract(text)) # this thing
.format('foo', 'bar') # is equivalent to this
```

Comment: You're right, anyway I forgot to mention that I am returning 4 arguments. If you would please explain me what does the imply